# Spring Boot - using inMemoryAuthentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven

I have this security config file in order to use in memory authentication in development phase

In my app. I have a User domain object:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {
..
}
```

In my security config class

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(User
                        .withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username(DEV_USER)
                        .password(DEV_PWD)
                        .roles("ADMIN").build());
    }
```

But when I get the User from the SecurityContextHolder:

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().
                getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

I got an error:

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User cannot be cast to com.iberia.domain.backend.User
```

But I couldn't find a way to construct a UserDetails object:

```
UserDetails
                            .withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username(DEV_USER)
                            .password(DEV_PWD)
                            .roles("ADMIN").build()
```

Comment: did you try 
 Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal instanceof UserDetails)
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername(); ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a custom user logged via InMemoryAuthentication with Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564532/how-to-get-a-custom-user-logged-via-inmemoryauthentication-with-spring-security)

Comment: If you need to use a custom user, you have to implement your own `UserDetailsService` as described in the other question. If you don't need your custom user, you can use the Spring Security's user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

```
String username = DEV_USER;
String encodedPassword = //encoded password
List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = getAuthorities("ADMIN");

User user = new User(username, encodedPassword, authList);
```

having : 
User==>`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

SimpleGrantedAuthority==>`org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority`

then you can cast user Object to `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` Object